# Id для пользователя

Tags: php, mysql

Как сделать для каждого пользователя свой id?
Нажимая на логин, попадаете, например, `index.php?id_user=12`.

Answer (score 2):

auto_increnent для поля ID в таблице. и будет счастье.

Comment: блин, писал в раздел php и по шаблону выскачело phpmyadmin ( гг 
я не чайно сюда написал, удалите если кто может

Comment: так у меня все есть) я чат пишу, ну так, чисто чтобы чему нибудь научиться, в общем так, id есть, но под ним все ники